# How to configure Azure App Service logging provider for an ASP.NET Core app?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to configure custom logging in my ASP.NET Core MVC app. The app is hosted on Azure App Service on Linux (free tier). The log files are not appearing, what am I doing wrong?

My configuration:

Following ASP.NET Core logging documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#azure-app-service-provider), I've added an Azure App Service logging provider to my app:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
                })
                .ConfigureServices(serviceCollection => serviceCollection
                    .Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options =>
                    {
                        options.FileName = "azure-diagnostics-";
                        options.FileSizeLimit = 10 * 1024;
                        options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 5;
                    })
                )
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseUrls("http://*:8080");
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

The logging configuration in app.settings:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I'm logging an info, warning and an error in my controller.

Following the Azure documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enable-application-logging-linuxcontainer), I've enabled logging to file system at Azure App -> App Service Logs:

[image: Azure config]

My app gets deployed fine and works. I'm expecting to find a log file with names 'azure-diagnostics' somewhere in the file system of the app. I've checked the file system by going to Azure App -> SSH and running:

```
find . -name '*azure-diagnostics*'
```

which doesn't return anything. I've also checked the file system using Kudu and VS Cloud Explorer, the files are not there. If I add the console logging provider, the logs appear in the standard Azure log files just fine. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't make it work using AzureWebAppDiagnostics logging provider, but I've managed to solve my problem by using Serilog provider with a file sink.

In program.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.File(@"../../LogFiles/azure-diagnostics-", fileSizeLimitBytes: 50 * 1024, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileCountLimit: 5)
                .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseUrls("http://*:8080");
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

UseSeriLog() call replaces the default MS log factory so I could also delete the logging configuration from appsettings.

Now I can see my custom log files appearing in the /home/LogFiles directory as expected.

Comment: This should not be marked as the correct answer, because it has a huge flaw!
With this implementation you ALWAYS write log files whereas with AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics the logger will only be enabled if Application Logging is enabled. If you enable Application logging it will automatically be disabled after 12hrs. File logging has a performance impact which we should take serious.

Comment: What I wanted was precisely that - to always log to file system. It was for a proof of concept project and whether it's a good idea for production use (probably it's not) is a separate question entirely. If you can make it work with AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics, please post a separate answer - I tried that but it didn't work, maybe Microsoft guys have fixed it since though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to setup the blob for storing the logs as well, can you try setting the file

```
.ConfigureServices(serviceCollection => serviceCollection
                .Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.FileName = "azure-diagnostics-";
                    options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
                    options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 5;
                }).Configure<AzureBlobLoggerOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.BlobName = "log.txt";
                }))
```

Check [SAMPLE app](https://github.com/tosetod/wedding-app-dotnet-core)

Comment: I think App Service on Linux doesn't support Blob storage for logs, as per documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enable-application-logging-linuxcontainer. In any case I wanted to log to the file system. I've been able to configure it by using Serilog with a file sink. I will post a separate answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default location for log files is in the `D:\home\LogFiles\Application` folder, and the default file name is `diagnostics-yyyymmdd.txt`.

Add the following provider in the program.cs.

```
.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
    logging.AddConsole();
})
```

Call `logger.LogWarning ("message");` in your code to write to log file. If you use `LogWarning` be sure to set Level to Warning or more detailed.

Please refer to this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/15212).

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what I tried if you read the description. The console provider worked fine and logged to the default location (no D drive since it's Linux), but I'm trying to set up logging to custom log files.