# How to write to the Azure Log Stream

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to get achieve something similar to `Console.WriteLine()` in Azure Portal. From what I can find, you need to use `System.Diagnostics.Trace` for that. But I cannot get anything to show.

Here is what I have done:

I have configured the App Service logs to write to the filesystem like this:

[image: Screenshot from Azure Portal]

And then I have made a simple end point, which tests three different ways of writing to the log:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult WriteToLog()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Getting all users... (TraceInformation)");
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Getting all users... (Trace.WriteLine)");
    Console.WriteLine("Getting all users (Console.WriteLine)");

    return Ok();
}
```

But nothing show in the **Log Stream** when I am calling the end point. Am I missing something? I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60696690/how-can-i-view-console-or-trace-output-in-an-azure-app-service-console-writelin) where one of the answers mentions configuring **AzureFileLoggerOptions**, but I can't really find anything concrete about how or why you need this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't see logs in Azure Log Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60133976/cant-see-logs-in-azure-log-stream)

Comment: You can refer to [How to configure Azure App Service logging provider for an ASP.NET Core app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59592417/how-to-configure-azure-app-service-logging-provider-for-an-asp-net-core-app) and [Diagnostic Log Stream](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Diagnostic-Log-Stream)

Comment: this was an excruciating exercise in futility.... apparently one must add extension `Microsft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppService` and then I had `builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();
builder.Logging.AddDebug();
builder.Logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();` Not entirely sue why this isn't better documented...
This is for a .net core 6 app